# Continuity of functions from complex numbers

Tags: analysis, continuity

i have a question about continuity. Suppose i have a function from $\Bbb{C}$ into a Banachalgebra $A$ for example $r\mapsto exp(ra)$  for a fixed $a\in A$. Do we have to prove continuity by epsilon-delta arguments or on a topological manner? Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give a general answer. In the concrete case you are asking I would do the following: let $r,s\in\mathbb C$ with $|r|\leq|s|$. Then
$$
\|e^{ra}-e^{sa}\|=\left\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(r^k-s^k)a^k}{k!}\right\|
\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|r^k-s^k|\,\|a\|^k}{k!}\leq|r-s|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|s|^{k-1}\,\|a\|^k}{(k-1)!}\\=|r-s|\,\|a\|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|s|^{k-1}\,\|a\|^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=|r-s|\,\|a\|\,e^{|s|\,\|a\|}.
$$
The estimate $|r^k-s^k|\leq2k|r-s|\,|s|^{k-1}$ follows from the Mean Value Theorem applied to the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: What do you mean by applying this to real and imaginary part? And should te estimation in the end not be free from s in the exponent?

Comment: It cannot be free from $s$; that would imply that the continuity is uniform, which it isn't. But it is not a big deal, because if $s$ is near $r$ you can bound it.

Comment: As for the MVT, it does not hold for complex functions. But we can consider the function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$, $g(t)=(tr+(1-t)s)^k$, and apply the MVT to it, to get $$r^k-s^k=g(1)-g(0)=g'(t_0)=k(t_0r+(1-t_0)s)^{k-1}(r-s).$$ So $$|r^k-s^k|\leq k|s|^{k-1}\,|r-s|.$$ (now I see that the $2$ in my answer was unneeded).

Comment: Thank you very helpful :-)